# How to apply an ellipsis to CheckBoxList control label text

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET CheckBoxList control which will be bound from server side code. It's rendering in UI perfectly but when the text property of any of list item contains more text say 200 characters then how to apply a ellipsis to that label?

My code:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:auto;">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstStates" CheckBoxes="true" Width="250px"
        RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" 
        runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="nowrap_list">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Alabama" Value="Alabama"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Alaska" Value="Alaska"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Arizona" Value="Arizona"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Arkansas" Value="Arkansas"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="California" Value="California"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Connecticut" Value="Connecticut"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="New YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew YorkNew York" Value="New York"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <div style="text-align:right;">
        <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
        <asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.nowrap_list label
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:block;
}
```

It's working OK but checkbox and text are rendered on two different lines.

Comment: This is not a CSS issue - perform your logic when getting the data on the server side and apply the ellipses there when character count exceeds 200.

Comment: i want to do it with css not in the server side i have applied the same css for a div and its working fine.

Comment: Can we see the markup for the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nowrap_list label {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I think you need to specify an actual width.

Comment: thanks worked with couple of changes to checkboxlist control. Have to check with % for the with attribute. The idea is to show the list in div with 90% width with div overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.nowrap_list label
{
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To avoid having the check box and the label on separate lines, the display style should be set to `inline-block` and the label width should be smaller than the CheckBoxList width.

Comment: thanks worked with couple of changes to checkboxlist control. Have to check with % for the with attribute. The idea is to show the list in div with 90% width with div overflow.